# intellij running scala script error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

anyone encountered this when running scala script >> edit configuration in intellij.

it works if the script is inside submodule/subproject. but throws the error below on parent module.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$definitions$.classExistentialType(Lscala/reflect/internal/Types$Type;Lscala/reflect/internal/Symbols$Symbol;)Lscala/reflect/internal/Types$Type;
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.processClassType$1(ClassfileParser.scala:670)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.sig2type$1(ClassfileParser.scala:679)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.sig2type$1(ClassfileParser.scala:709)
```